# Column Questions.UserId doesn't exist in associated model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have two models: **Questions** and **Users**, with one-to-many relationship specified between them. I'm using sequelize-cli to generate models and migrations. With migrations I manually added foreign key attribute in **Questions** database, named **authorId** in this way:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  async up (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.addColumn('Questions', 'authorId', {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      references: {
        model: 'Users',
        key: 'id'
      }
    });
  },

  async down (queryInterface) {
    await queryInterface.removeColumn('Questions', 'authorId');
  }
};
```

My models:

**question.js**

```
'use strict';

const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Question extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      models.Question.belongsTo(models.User);
    }
  }

  Question.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      authorId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        references: 'Users',
        key: 'id'
      }
    }, 
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Question',
    }
  );
  
  return Question;
};
```

**user.js**

```
'use strict';

const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      models.User.hasMany(models.Question, { foreignKey: 'authorId' });
    }
  }

  User.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  
  return User;
};
```

In order to use custom foreign key attribute (**authorId**), docs provides an [example](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#options-1) where foreignKey property is added to model just once for **hasMany** relationship:

```
Team.hasMany(Player, {
  foreignKey: 'clubId'
});
Player.belongsTo(Team);
```

But that's doesn't work in my case. When trying to retrieve user instance with question(s) included, an error gets thrown:

```
name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
parent: error: column Questions.UserId doesn't exist
```

In order to solve the problem I have to add options object with foreignKey to both **hasMany** and **belongsTo** methods like that:

```
class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      models.User.hasMany(models.Question, { foreignKey: 'authorId' });
    }
}

class Question extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      models.Question.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'authorId' });
    }
}
```

So basically my question is why we have to specify foreignKey property in both of the associations methods?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking these two associations are independent and they know nothing about each other options like `foreignKey`. Keeping that in mind we should always indicate the same `foreignKey` option in both paired associations if we need to use custom foreign key column name. You can look at the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73532587/error-unknown-column-table1-table2primarykey-in-field-list-in-sequelize/73532840#73532840) that I already answered recently.